# Laravel/blade component with conditions

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Is there any way how I can use something similar to `@can('update', $project)` but on a component?

The following doesn't work;

```
<x-input @cannot('update', $project) disabled="disabled" @endcannot />
```

and I can't do;

```
<x-input :disabled="@cannot('update', $project)" />
```

to get a `true`/`false` value into the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add `disabled` to the props of your component

```
@props(['disabled' => false])

<input
@if($disabled) disabled @endif
{{ $attributes }}
/>
```

Then use it like this

```
<x-input :disabled="Auth::user()->cannot('update', $project)" />
```

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was looking for! I'm using custom policies so not really sure how `Auth::user()` works, but it does what I need so I'm happy. Thanks!

Comment: `@cannot` is a shortcut for `@if(Auth::user()->cannot('update', $project))` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#via-blade-templates But it definitely uses policies :)

Comment: Ok sweet! Related question. There is only an `@elsecan` version of it and no `@else` right? So if I want to use `@can` for something I also need a second block of `@cannot` for the opposite?

Comment: Oh, actually. There seem to be an else version. Not sure what I did earlier.

Comment: You also have `@elsecan()`,  `@endcan`, `@endcannot` etc.. But for the `:disabled` it will be a a bit tricky as you need an inline condition or a variable

Comment: Yes! But back to `@else`. It's only listed under their `@can` option in the doc, none of the others, but maybe they just don't have any examples of it for the rest and it still works.

Comment: Since `@can(...)` will generate `if(Auth::user()->can(...))` behind the scene, `@else` will work like a regular `else`. Also you can close with `@endif` instead of `@endcan` but it won't really have much sense when reading the code. But you can :)

Comment: Very interesting. My OCD and code editor wouldn't like switching up the tags for auto formatting so I'll stick to the conventions! Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
@can('update', $project)
     <x-input />
@endcan
```

Comment: Thanks! Problem is that I still want everyone to see the input, but add disable if you can't edit it (of course with server side validation as well). With your solution I'd need a second block with `@cannot` and another input element. Would love to slim it down to just a condition or pass through a true/false to disable.